# Unable to load images through handlebars templating

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

Image is not being loaded though `{{post.story}}` is being displayed correctly. Console displays a `404 error`.

My `homepage.hbs` contains the following code:

```
{{#each data as |post|}}
     //dispayed correctly
     {{post.story}}
     //not being displayed
     <img src= {{post.image}}>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your img `src` in a string.

```
<img src="{{post.image}}">
```

Comment: @HarshitBisht Can you kindly copy and post the `<img>` element from your page source?

Comment: <img  src= "/home/harshitbisht96/WebstormProjects/gridfsandmulter/uploads/avatar-1501541056425.png"  >

Comment: So I'm guessing that you see an error in your JS console along the lines of "Resource cannot be retrieved." Can you post file structure of your project?

Comment: Error in the console is -- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).The 'data' is being coming from the javascript file                                                                       
  
        imagesDb.find({}).toArray().then(function (data) {
            res.render('homepage', {data: data});
            })
     The homepage is the template which I am rendering.

Comment: Try changing your img src to "uploa‌​ds/avatar-1501541056‌​425.png"

Comment: The error I am getting is GET http://localhost:1111/home/harshitbisht96/WebstormProjects/gridfsandmulter/uploads/avatar-1501541056425.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150666/discussion-between-matthewninja-and-harshit-bisht).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can specify the static folder for the express middleware to look for static stuff like images, css files etc.

paste the below code where you have defined your express middleware (typically app.js or server.js)

```js
// create an instance of express module
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('<path of the directory>'));
```

here the name of the directory should be directory where such static files are located.

Hope it helps!